# I need to scrape data between the <Br> tags using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi actually I was trying to **scrape things between the br tags**.
For example take the below case:-

```
<blockquote>
               <font face="Garamond" size="5"><br>
                 <b>ICM Partners<br></b>
                 730 Fifth Avenue<br>
                 New York, NY 10019<br>
                 (212) 556-5600<br>
                 <br>
                 (<i>Gelfman Schneider</i>)<br>
                 <br>
                 <a href="http://www.icmtalent.com"target="_blank">http://www.icmtalent.com</a> 
                 <br> </font></blockquote>
```

> **ICM Partners**
>
>                  730 Fifth Avenue
>                  New York, NY 10019
>                  (212) 556-5600
>                  
>                  (*Gelfman Schneider*)
>                  
>                  http://www.icmtalent.com

Actually I want to split it into **Company's name , Company's Address, Company's Contact number and Company's Website.**

I know I can split it by split function `.split(<br>)` and then place the thing in order but sometime the ***address is not just of 1 or 2 lines and even in many cases contact number is also not given***. So I can't accurately place anything.
Take this case for example:-

```
<blockquote>
            <font face="Garamond" size="5"><br>
            <b>The Agency</b><br>
            24 Pottery Lane<br>
            Holland Park<br>
            London W11 4LZ<br>
            <br>
            <a href="http://theagency.co.uk" target="_blank">http://theagency.co.uk</a><br>
            </font></blockquote>
```

> **The Agency**
>                                 24 Pottery Lane
>                                 Holland Park
>                                 London W11 4LZ
>                                 
>                                 http://theagency.co.uk

**Hope you can solve it.
Thank You in advance.**

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your attempt in the form of a [mre]. PS. It's *scrape* not *scrap*.

Comment: you've just discovered why [web semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) are important. there are too many guesses to make and it really looks like this problem is too broad. for example the phone numbers: the easiest way to catch them is by writing regular expressions. do you know how to do that?

Comment: Could you please share an example of the code you are using to parse this HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Extracting such data can be very error prone and would need to be tested on a larger dataset.

One possible approach would be:

1. Split the whole entry using `.stripped_strings` to give you a list of possible lines
2. Use a regular express to attempt to locate which line contains a telephone number.
   If not found set the end of the address to be all but the last line.
3. Create an entry by assuming the first entry is the company name, following entries are an address up to `address_end`, optional telephone entry if found.
4. Assume the last entry is the website.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

re_tel = re.compile(r'[0-9() -]{5,}$')

html = """
    <blockquote>
        <font face="Garamond" size="5"><br>
        <b>ICM Partners<br></b>
        730 Fifth Avenue<br>
        New York, NY 10019<br>
        (212) 556-5600<br>
        <br>
        (<i>Gelfman Schneider</i>)<br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.icmtalent.com"target="_blank">http://www.icmtalent.com</a> 
        <br></font>
    </blockquote>
    
    <blockquote>
        <font face="Garamond" size="5"><br>
        <b>The Agency</b><br>
        24 Pottery Lane<br>
        Holland Park<br>
        London W11 4LZ<br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://theagency.co.uk" target="_blank">http://theagency.co.uk</a><br>
            </font>
    </blockquote>    
    """
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for blockquote in soup.find_all('blockquote'):
    fields = list(blockquote.stripped_strings)
    tel = ''
    address_end = -1

    for index, field in enumerate(fields):
        if re_tel.match(field):
            tel = field
            address_end = index
            break

    fields = [fields[0], ', '.join(fields[1:address_end]), tel, fields[-1]]
    print(fields)
```

For your two examples this would give:

```
['ICM Partners', '730 Fifth Avenue, New York, NY 10019', '(212) 556-5600', 'http://www.icmtalent.com']
['The Agency', '24 Pottery Lane, Holland Park, London W11 4LZ', '', 'http://theagency.co.uk']
```

This will no doubt need to be improved upon when tested on a bigger dataset.